# noClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/Handler when running weblogic.deployer from command line (Weblogic 8.1 )

Tags: deployment, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear, weblogic8.x

When I run weblogic.deployer from the command line in my localhost, I get the following error

noClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/Handler.

here is the command I run

```
java -cp C:\BEA\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar; weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -password weblogic -redeploy -name my-ear.ear
```

Any Idea where to find that class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is run setDomainEnv or commEnv to set the classpath.

Comment: Thanks. that took care of it.